# async/await for fetching data with spinner

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, es6-promise

**Goal**

To have a spinner running till data loads.

**What I did**

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@kkomaz/react-to-async-await-553c43f243e2)
I also tried regular promise and `then` but no success.

**What happens**

the `console.log` is displaying "boom" right off the bat, so not waiting for data fetching. No errors.

**EventPage.js**

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            panelView: true,
            loading: true
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
        try {
            await this.props.fetchEvents();
            this.setState({loading: false});
            console.log("BOOM")
        } catch {

        }

    }
render() {
        const {loading} = this.state;
        const {panelView} = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return <Loader />
        }
        return (
            (Actual page)
        )
    }
```

eventActionCreator fetchEvents

```
export const fetchEvents = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3090/events');
            dispatch(setEvent(response.data));
            return response.data;
        } catch (e) {
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

The console is only to show code is waiting for fetch to execute, it doesn't.

Comment: Please add a live example with the JS snippet feature from Stackoverflow.

Comment: When you say "No success" -- what is actually happening? Are there errors in the console? Does "BOOM" get written?

Comment: @bluejack I added the details

Comment: seems no error in your code.. can you add more details or working demo?

Comment: @ma_dev_15 yes there is... Look at the answer below along with a live demo on code sandbox... He's setting loading to false in his setState... and then a conditional to render Loading if true...

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach

```
state = {
    products: [],
    loading: true,
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    // try catch just to make sure we had no errors
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://api');
      // wait for json to be ready
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        data,
      });
      // console.log(product.data.attributes)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }



render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Contents>
          {loading ? 'loading..' : <Products data={data} />}
        </Contents>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. The problem was that I returned data from action creator and not a promise based action.

so, instead of

```
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3090/events');
            dispatch(setEvent(response.data));
            return response.data;
```

it should have been

```
return  axios.get('http://localhost:3090/events')
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(setEvent(response.data));
            });
```

[Issue that helped me resolve it](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676#issuecomment-215413478)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have it backward... You're initializing your state to true and then setting it to false in cdm... Then you are checking if loading is true if so render the Loader... Of course, it's not true, you set it to false...

Change to this:

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            panelView: true,
            loading: false <- here
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({loading: true}); <- here

        try {
            await this.props.fetchEvents();
            this.setState({loading: false}); <- and here...
            console.log("BOOM")
        } catch {

        }

    }
render() {
        const {loading} = this.state;
        const {panelView} = this.state;
        if (loading) {
            return <Loader />
        }
        return (
            (Actual page)
        )
    }
```

Here is a live Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/r0w381qw3p

Comment: So here there is a problem
`this.setState({loading: true}); 1

Comment: if you need loading as true in Component mount so set the default state as true rather than doing in componentDidMount as it will rerender the component